# IndexOutofBounds Exception when finding a peak in 2d arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, data-structures, indexoutofboundsexception

I've clearly defined all the limits, yet I keep getting index out of bounds exception. Can anyone have a look and tell me where I could be wrong. I'm trying to find multiple peaks in a 2d array. Thanks.

```
Scanner o = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter length of array: ");
    int row = o.nextInt();
    System.out.println("A 2d array of " + row + "x" + row + " has been generated");

    int[][] table = new int[row][row];


    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            table[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            System.out.print(table[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    int n = row - 1;
    for (int a = 0; a < row; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < row; b++){
            if (a == 0 &&  b == 0 && table[a][b] > table[a+1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b+1]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
            else if (a == 0 && table[a][b] > table[a][b-1] && table[a][b] > table[a+1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b+1]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
            if (b == 0 && table[a][b] > table[a-1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a+1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b+1]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
            if (table[a][b] > table[a][b-1] && table[a][b] > table[a-1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b+1] && table[a][b] > table[a+1][b]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
            if (a == n && b == n && table[a][b] > table[a-1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b-1]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
            if (a == n && table[a][b] > table[a][b+1] && table[a][b] > table[a-1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b-1]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
            if (b == n && table[a][b] > table[a+1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a-1][b] && table[a][b] > table[a][b-1]){
                System.out.println(table[a][b] + " is a peak");
            }
        }
```

Comment: In last iteration a+1 will be out of bounds. Example row=4 in last iteration a will be 3 so 3+1 is 4 which is out of bound because arrays start at 0. Same for b

Comment: @bakero98 but I've already defined n for last row iterations. if a or b == n then other instructions are provided

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the the third through seventh `if`s should be `else if`s. Consider the case `a=b=0`: The first `if` is executed, the second one is skipped, but the third one is executed again and gives an error as `a-1` is not a valid row. As a side note, this can also print the message several times for a given element.

If your aim is to find elements that are strictly larger than their (up to) four neighbors, may I suggest padding the matrix with very large values? That will get rid of all the checks and shorten the code considerably. Something like:

```java
int[][] table = new int[row + 2][row + 2];

for (int i = 0; i < row + 2; i++) {
  table[0][i] = table[row + 1][i] = 100;
  table[i][0] = table[i][row + 1] = 100;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++) {
    table[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

// ... print the matrix (skipped for brevity) ...

for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++) {
    if (table[i][j] > table[i][j - 1] &&
        table[i][j] > table[i - 1][j] &&
        table[i][j] > table[i][j + 1] &&
        table[i][j] > table[i + 1][j]) {
      System.out.println(table[i][j] + " is a peak");
  }
}
```